# Extract correlation metric rho from correlation test

Tags: r, correlation

How can I extract the ***rho*** value from a **correlation test**?

For example, here the value of interest is **-0.7356124**:

```
cor.test(x,y, alternative = "less", method = "spearman")
    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  x and y
S = 60.746, p-value = 0.04781
alternative hypothesis: true rho is less than 0
sample estimates:
       rho 
-0.7356124
```

Data:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y <- c(1,0,-1,-1,0,-2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `estimate`

```
unname(cor.test(x,y, alternative = "less", method = "spearman")$estimate)
[1] -0.7356124
```